# OpenAPi Typescript/Axios generator: 3 mediatypes supported but only one client method generated

Tags: openapi, openapi-generator, springdoc, openapi-generator-maven-plugin

I have an API with an endpoint that can produces 3 differents mediatypes. The api description looks like this:

```
{
  "openapi" : "3.0.1",
  "info" : {
    "title" : "OpenAPI definition",
    "version" : "v0"
  },
  "servers" : [ {
    "url" : "http://localhost:11002",
    "description" : "Generated server url"
  } ],
  "paths" : {
    "/services/v1/something" : {
      "get" : {
        "tags" : [ "something-controller" ],
        "operationId" : "getSomething",
        "responses" : {
          "200" : {
            "description" : "OK",
            "content" : {
              "text/plain" : {
                "schema" : {
                  "type" : "string"
                }
              },
              "application/json" : {
                "schema" : {
                  "type" : "array",
                  "items" : {
                    "$ref" : "#/components/schemas/SomethingDTO"
                  }
                }
              },
              "application/.htpasswd" : {
                "schema" : {
                  "type" : "string"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
 
(...)
```

My expectation is that the typescript/axios generator (openapi-generator-maven-plugin, version 6.6.0)  would generate a client with one method for each mediatype. Unfortunately, only one method is generated for the first mediatype listed. Is there a way to fix that?